# Boostrap 4 make container as large as children

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a page like the one in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1es8w5qf/

The page is mainly for visualizing data in a pivot table (using pivottable.js). The problem (shown in the fiddle) is that when the pivot table gets too wide, it overflows the bootstrap container. Is there anyway to make the container (and the row and thus the columns) to grow as wide as the children?

Of course I could also make them to just scroll when overflown, however, I tried setting the pivot ui's container `row` to `overflow:scroll` and both Chrome and Firefox seemed to not be able to handle that very well: the table would take some *seconds* to render when you scroll (that doesn't happen on the fiddle I provided. I guess it's because my dataset is *way* larger than the data used in the fiddle).

I've also tried setting only the pivot ui's container `col`to overflow, however that makes the col to not take all the viewport width.

Comment: Table overflowing horizontally is always an issue. In my opinion, you just have to add scrollbar if the table is getting too wide. You can take a look at `.table-responsive` from `boostrap4` documentation and see if that's what you want. If you don't want scrollbar, the only thing I can see is to redesign your layout to utilize vertical spaces. You can't make the container as large as children. Your user's monitor has limited width after all. At some point they have to scroll.

Comment: @DavidLiang Yea, I expect scrolling to happen if the table gets too wide, of course. The problem is that if I set `overflow:auto` or something similar on the parent, the table gets mostly unresponsive. It takes too long to render when you scroll. However, when using the browser "native" scroll (that is, the table simply gets too large and the browser does its job providing a scroll to the entire page, just like shown in the fiddle), there are no performance issues. The only issue that remains is the styling: the bootstrap container is smaller than the table inside it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to fit table container horizontally, right? just set pivot-ui width to 100% just like this:

```
.pivot-ui {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Nope. I've set the width in the fiddle to 1200px purposefully, to simulate when the Pivot Table gets too wide. The user can remove or add columns from the pivot table at his discretion, so I have no control at how wide it will be. I'm trying to make another fiddle right now using the actual pivot table library. I'll update the question when it's ready.

Comment: Ok, got it. Have you tried "overflow-x: scroll" on the parent? I tried and it worked.

Comment: Yes, however, as I said in the question, the table takes seconds to render when scrolling with `overflow` set on the parent.

Comment: I don't think you need to set the width to 1200px to simulate. Remove that line in your css. Your table will be adjusted to the width of your view port since you defined `<div class="col-sm-12">`. Now, if you want to force the table to this size, then you wont have a responsive layout, or at least you could not use boostratp definitions.

Comment: I've updated your fiddle. Added a div with table class as a parent of #output, and I gave styles to that. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this if I understood your qn

```
.pivot-ui {
  width:1200px;
  background-color:red;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried setting `overflow:auto`, `overflow-x:scroll` on almost all of the parents (the pivot-ui div, its `col parent`, its `row` parent and its `container-fluid` parent), however, as I said in the question, the table takes seconds to render when scrolling with overflow set on the parent.

Comment: I don't see an issue in your new jsfiddle

Comment: If you scroll you'll see that the table is wider than the bootstrap container.

Comment: can you show it in printscreen via paint what is the problem ?, looking at you code am confused, It will be much better to see exactly what u need to change